# Switching Firebase configuration file at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, configuration-files, firebase-analytics

My iOS app uses two Firebase configuration files, one for development and one for production. How can I switch between the two during runtime? When I attempt the switch with `[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];`, I get the error:

```
 Default app has already been configured.
```

So I have tried to clear the current config `[FIRApp deleteApp]` before switching to the other config, however the `deleteApp` method is a private method and is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when initializing your firebase :

```
    NSString *filePath;

#ifdef DEBUG
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-Debug" ofType:@"plist"];
#else
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-Live" ofType:@"plist"];
#endif

    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

Answer (score 1):

I was calling the `deleteApp` method incorrectly. It should be called on `defaultApp`, eg.:

```
 [[FIRApp defaultApp] deleteApp:^(BOOL success) { ... }];
```